# Show LOADING in innerHTML while object is being loaded

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript function that load contents return by contacts.php into DIV id contacts-container, it takes a lot of time to complete the task. I want to show "LOADING.." text in the DIV id contacts-container while contents are being loaded.

```
function load_contacts() {
    document.getElementById("contacts-container").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="contacts.php" ></object>';
}
```

I want solution in pure JavaScript.

Comment: did you tried something already?

Comment: You can load your page contact.php using ajax. display a loading on the execution of the function and hide it when success.

Comment: *"I want solution in pure JavaScript."* -- perfect way of encouraging generous people to take a few minutes of their life and help you. Flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about some more JS?

```
function load_contacts() {
    var el = document.createElement("object"),
        target = document.getElementById("contacts-container")

    target.innerHTML = "<span>Loading...</span>";

    el.onload = function() {
        target.firstChild.remove();
    }

    el.setAttribute("type","text/html");
    el.setAttribute("data","contacts.php");
    target.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do with ajax. For this my suggestion, you must Jquery Ajax. For example,

```
$("#loadingElement").html("Loading");

$.load("#contacts-container",{},"contacts.php",function(){

  $("#loadingElement").html("");

});
```

Comment: From the [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*